# Edit a File in Python and write the results on a new file but only in specific areas

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, editing

I want to make a script doing the following:

i have file_ori.txt that its contents are like this ( numbers are just line numbers not actual text )

```
1 This is test line with random text
2 This is also a line with lalala text
3 This is that and this and that of a line
4 start sequence
5 This isn't also a line with lalala text
6 This is test line with random text
7 This is also a line with lalala text
8 end sequence
9 This is test line with random text
```

What i want to accomplice is a change the word "line" with word "Pine" in the whole file but only pass the changes in the new file between `start sequence` and `end sequence` and the result would be this :

```
1 This is test line with random text
2 This is also a line with lalala text
3 This is that and this and that of a line
4 start sequence
5 This isn't also a Pine with lalala text
6 This is test Pine with random text
7 This is also a Pine with lalala text
8 end sequence
9 This is test line with random text
```

It is crucial in my case that i don't want to split the file prior the replace but only after. I have to work on the full read.

```
f = open(file_ori.txt, "r")
full_read = f.read()

full_read = full_read.replace('line', 'Pine')

............. I don't know how to continue

f = open(file_ori_edit.txt, 'w')
    f.write(full_read)
    f.close()
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
start = 'start sequence'
end = 'end sequence'
parse = False
result = []
with open(filename) as infile:
    for line in infile:      #Iterate each line
        line = line.strip()
        if start == line:    #check for start sequence
            parse = True
        if end == line:      #check for end sequence
            parse = False

        if parse:   #Replace ONLY between sequence
            line = line.replace('line', 'Pine')
        result.append(line+"\n")

with open(filename, "w") as outfile:
    outfile.writelines(result)
```